# Using reflection to iterate over struct's struct members and calling a method on it

Tags: go, methods, struct, reflection, interface

I have a `struct` that has one or more `struct` members. Each member is expected to implement a `Validator` interface.

I want to use reflection to iterate over all `struct` members and call the interface's `Validate()` method.  For example:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "reflect"

type Validator interface {
    Validate()
}

type T1 struct {
    S string
}

func (p *T1) Validate() {
    fmt.Println("HERE 1")
}

type T2 struct {
    S string
}

func (p *T2) Validate() {
    fmt.Println("HERE 2")
}

type Top struct {
    S1 T1
    S2 T2
}

func main() {
    var t Top

    r := reflect.ValueOf(t)
    for i := 0; i < r.NumField(); i++ {
        f := r.Field(i)
        if f.Kind() == reflect.Struct {
            validator := f.Interface().(Validator)
            validator.Validate()
        }
    }
}
```

When run, it outputs:

> panic: interface conversion: main.T1 is not main.Validator: missing method Validate

If I change the `Validate()` methods to accept value (rather than pointer) receivers, then it works. However, I *want* to use pointer receivers since the `struct`s may grow to be large.

How can I change the reflection code to work where the methods are defined taking pointer receivers?

I also tried using this line:

```
            validator := f.Addr().Interface().(Validator)
```

to get a pointer, but it then outputs:

> panic: reflect.Value.Addr of unaddressable value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of your values are addressable, so you can't call any methods on them with pointer receivers.

If the `S1` and `S2` fields can't be pointers, you can still address them if you have a pointer to the `Top` struct:

```
r := reflect.ValueOf(&t).Elem()
for i := 0; i < r.NumField(); i++ {
    f := r.Field(i)
    if f.Kind() == reflect.Struct {
        validator := f.Addr().Interface().(Validator)
        validator.Validate()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

"Top.S1" is of type "T1" and is different from "*T1" type defined "Validate()".

If you change "Top.S1" to "*T1" type and modify the field type checking, your code will work properly.

```
type Top struct {
    S1 *T1
    S2 *T2
}

func main() {
    t := Top{&T1{}, &T2{}}

    r := reflect.ValueOf(t)
    for i := 0; i < r.NumField(); i++ {
        f := r.Field(i)
        if f.Kind() == reflect.Ptr && f.Elem().Kind() == reflect.Struct {
            validator, ok := f.Interface().(Validator)
            if ok {
                validator.Validate()
            } else {
                fmt.Println("not ok")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/hHqP6WdMYqT

Comment: JimB's answer requires no changes to the data structures.